# Sharepoint 2010 every domain user logged in show system account instead of domain\user

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After my SharePoint Foundation recovered from "Cannot connect to the Configuration Database ". I found my Sharepoint site collection got some exceptions.

When I try to log in with a domain user account, I find the right corner display states "System account" instead of Domain\Username. The account also has the system account permission. Then I checked every computer in the domain, every user had this issue.

But when I went to  Library setting from the homepage I found the account to have the correct name, but when I went to other page, the page displays system account again.

I really have no ideas about this issue. Can anyone give me some suggestions to resolve this?